# How use setOnClickListner on "custom" toolbar's menu items?

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener, android-toolbar, menuitem

I want to set `OnClick` behaviour on menu items of custom toolbar in an activity. I found many answers of same thing but on the `actionbar` which comes from theme, no answer was found for clicking items of menu of custom material toolbar.

Note: I don't want to add Image button on toolbar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as with standard ActionBar.

1) Replace ActionBar with your own material toolbar like so:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ...
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            ...
```

2) Override OnCreateOptions menu as usual:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_layout,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

3) Handle clicks:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.register: {
                ...
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: My code written for Fragment. If you do it inside an Activity then you do not need this line setHasOptionsMenu(true); (can be ommited)